# MySQL, GROUP_CONCAT & GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

Here's my working query:

```
SELECT 
d.*, g.name game, 
 (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(p.name) FROM shows_players p 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM shows_map) sm ON sm.player_id = p.id 
  WHERE sm.show_id = d.id AND sm.game_id = g.id) players 
FROM shows_dates d 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM shows_map 
           WHERE player_id = 5 GROUP BY show_id, game_id) m ON d.id = m.show_id 
LEFT JOIN shows_games g ON g.id = m.game_id
```

It's a fine query until adding the "WHERE player_id =" line. Then it returns some rows with no data. How do I clean this up and get rid of these?

Thank you

Comment: This is quite a mess....I'm not really sure what's going on here, but the joins on subqueries etc might make this a really slow query. You might be better of by asking a different question: starting with your goal and your data structure, how to make a query that gets your data?

Comment: I suspect your problem is due to the LEFT JOIN with the sub-query and filtering the sub-query.  Avoid the LEFT JOIN if possible; otherwise, consider filtering in the (currently absent) WHERE clause for the main query instead of the sub-query.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I believe there's a perfomance question whenever to use WHERE inside or outside the m-table. From what I've heard, it's better to filter inside custom tables and better to filter outside of normal tables like the d-table.

Comment: Nanne, you're probably right. This is the best I could get today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is probably to change `LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM shows_map` to `INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM shows_map`.

I imagine that you get some empty NULL data since you're using LEFT JOIN.

And your query is quite the mess.

Comment: Exactly as you said Robin. Using INNER JOIN for the second "(SELECT * FROM shows_map" solved this one.

Comment: Also allowed me to drop the "GROUP BY". Thanks!